# Where are my Results?

Tags: ibm-q-experience

I've successfully used IBM Q Experience for quite a while now.  But the interface seems to have changed.  After I run a simulation on my quantum circuit, I go to Results but I don't see the answer in the form of a histogram like I used to.  Where is it?

Answer (score 2):

With out seeing what you see, I can't say much. How many qubits were you using? If you use `ibmq_16_melbourne` and measure all the qubit then you don't expect to see the histogram plot, and you shouldn't since there are $2^{15} = 32768$ eigenbasis.... I believe in those cases, you can download the generated `cvs` file.

---

However, to see if the histogram plot still shows up on small enough problem (something of 5 qubit or less) I ran a quick test on my account on using the following circuit:

[image]

and when I go to my `Result` tab on IBMQ Experience, I clicked on the result for this run and still see the histogram plot:

[image]